# What the difference between ChannelHandlerContext.executor() and Channel.eventLoop() in netty4?

Tags: netty

What the difference between `ChannelHandlerContext.executor()` and `Channel.eventLoop()` in netty4?

when I want to run a task in handler which one should i use?

```
ctx.executor().submit(task);
ctx.channel().eventLoop().submit(task);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this is the same. It is up to you what method to choose. You can also have a look into `AbstractChannelHandlerContext.executor()` method and find that context repeats channel code :

```
public EventExecutor executor() {
    if (executor == null) {
        return channel().eventLoop();
    } else {
        return executor;
    }
}
```

However, netty allows you to assign handlers within same pipeline for different EventExecutors. In that case returned result for channel and context may be different. But for submitting a task this is not big deal.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Can you solve my another question about whether business code should run in a task or just write in the channelRead0 method?(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617593/where-should-i-put-business-logic-in-netty4-in-chanelread0-or-run-a-task)