# where should I put business logic in netty4? In chanelRead0() or run a task?

Tags: netty

where should I put business logic in netty4?

Should I just put my code in `@Override channelRead0()` or run a task in it?
I know both of that will run into the same IO eventLoop, but what's the differences between them? which one is better?

Solution 1:

```
@Override 
channelRead0(){
    business code;
}
```

Solution 2:

```
@Override 
channelRead0(){
    ctx.executor().submit(new task(){business code});
    //or ctx.channel().eventLoop().submit(new task(){business code});
}
```

Comment: If you use NioEventLoop, unless you do some customization, the task is actually submitted to the task queue of the thread that executes your `channelRead0` method :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't use any blocking operations (read from DB for example) `channelRead0` would be totally fine. In general it is up to you to decide. `Submit` method is more likely for cases when you need to execute asynchronous operation or timed event. For blocking events it is better to create separate executor.

Comment: Why would it be ok to have some slow operation being submitted to the event loop? It would still block the thread. Async ops and timers I agree it's OK, slow operations I don't think so.

Comment: Agree. Edited the answer.